# How to log all domains accessed?

Tags: logs, proxy, http, tcpdump, domain

Maybe I could use `tcpdump`, filter out all non-HTTP packets to reduce disk consumption, and then parse the output looking for domain names. Maybe there is a better solution. Do you know one?

Comment: The target machine is a Tomato router, but I'll accept answers regarding generic unix/linux systems

Comment: I setting up a DNS server and forcing users to use it an option?

Comment: @Lekensteyn everybody uses my router as the DNS already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to get the domains accessed via `http` you could setup up a transparent http-proxy with [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) or [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) and evaluate the log file.

1. Set up the proxy
   Install and configure the proxy, that he listen for example on the address `127.0.0.1:8080` and enable logging.
2. Set up the firewall rule
   Write a firewall rule, which redirect all outgoing traffic to the port `80` to the address of proxy `127.0.0.1:8080`, which then forwards the traffic to requested domain.
3. Parse the log file
   Set up a parser to extract all the accessed domains from the log file.

This solution has it's up and downs:

- UP's:

  - your users don't have to change something on their system, browser, ...
  - you gain some capabilities, like caching, filtering, ... depending on the used proxy
  - you can expand it to log other protocols like `https`, `ftp` ... when the proxy supports it
- DOWN's:

  - it's another system you to have manage and that's maybe failing
  - it's raises some **legal/privacy** issues, when you keep extensive logs on your users browsing habits